# Should DTOs represent nested entity strutctures, or should I have my pathing set up to have an endpoint for each nested object?

Tags: rest, http, design-patterns, api-design, dto

For example, lets say I have an entity that looks like this.

```
public class PersonEntity {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public List<CarEntity> cars;
}
```

**Option 1**
*GET /people/1*

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Sagget,
    "cars": [
        (could be just IDs or the full Car DTOs)
    ]
}
```

**Option 2**
*GET /people/1*

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Sagget"
}
```

*GET /people/1/cars*

```
[
    {
        "make": "Honda",
        "model": "Accord",
        "year": 1992
    }
]
```

I feel like option 2 is more RESTful. But I also wonder about instances where you will need the full nested set of objects in every scenario. Should I still design it this way in that case? Also, what if the Car entity has nested objects? I would need a third endpoint to navigate down into the cars child entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the entire `cars` dto in `people`, you will be able to display a person and all the cars this person has on the same page which I think is a more user friendly design.

If you make a separate endpoint for a `person's` `cars` then the user would first navigate to the `person's` page and then the user would have to click again in order to see this `person's` `cars` which may even require another page load

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I probably should have mentioned this is for an API not a website. So a front end consuming the API could show a list of users and all their cars by first calling /people/1 and then calling /people1/cars and joining the data on their side.

Comment: I understand that this is an API and my answer is considering the fact that it is an API. You should simply write two endpoints which are `person/id` this one should return a person object and a list of car objects that this person has. And `persons` this one will return a list `persons` and each `person` in this list does not need to have a `cars` list